# How do i add edit shortcut icon in wordpress without using selective refresh

Tags: theme-customizer, icon

I am developing a theme and I wonder if there anyway I can add a visual edit shortcut without selective refresh?

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport        = 'postMessage';

$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.site-title a',
    'render_callback' => 'twentyfifteen_customize_partial_blogname',
) );
```

Can I do like

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport        = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport = 'postMessage';

$wp_customize->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.site-title a',
    'render_callback' => 'twentyfifteen_customize_partial_blogname',
) );
```

Actually it works and gives the desired result .. but I am using Kirki as my framework and for some reason I am not able to do it. I just don't want to use the default selective refresh i want to use my own javascript function with postMessage and I am not able to implement the selector tag here.

Here is my code:

```
Kirki::add_field( 'theme_config', array(
    'type'     => 'text',
    'settings' => 'about_us_video_setting',
    'label'    => __( 'Video Link', 'rst' ),
    'section'  => 'about_us_section',
    'default'  => esc_attr__( 'youtube.com', 'rst' ),
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
    'partial_refresh' => array( 
    'about_us_video_setting' => array( 
        'selector' => '#youtube-video', 
        'render_callback' => 'show_video', 
    ) ),
    'active_callback'    => array(
        array(
            'setting'  => 'is_front_page',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value'    => true,
        ),
    ),

) );
```

what i want is

```
Kirki::add_field( 'theme_config', array(
    'type'     => 'text',
    'settings' => 'about_us_video_setting',
    'label'    => __( 'Video Link', 'rst' ),
    'section'  => 'about_us_section',
    'default'  => esc_attr__( 'youtube.com', 'rst' ),
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
     'selector' => '#youtube-video',        
    'active_callback'    => array(
        array(
            'setting'  => 'is_front_page',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value'    => true,
        ),
    ),

) );
```

Is this.. as even if I give transport as postMessage what is does is just default refresh instead of using my own javascript which is

```
( function( $ ) {
// Change the previewed URL to the selected page when changing the page_for_posts.
wp.customize( 'about_us_video_setting', function( setting ) {
    setting.bind( function( url ) {
        $('.embed-responsive-item').attr('src',url);
    });
});

} )( jQuery );
```

Just want to clarify as I did not find any documentation.  Is it a criteria to use selective refresh to show edit shorcuts?

from edit shorcuts I mean this pencil icon [image]
which takes you to the desired location to edit.

Comment: i think what you need something like (https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE)

Comment: it has nothing to do with codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE its related to wordpress customizer api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this by using **__return_false** . The downside is you get a double refresh as it checks for a partial and then returns "false" which results in a full refresh. This is problematic if you are using javascript only to show a "realtime" preview. In that case, you'd have to go with Weston Ruter's solution.

If you are not actually using a postMessage preview and just want the shortcut to show up, then it is not a big deal as you need the full refresh anyway.

I am not sure why they haven't built in these partial edit shortcuts for those using javascript only.

In kirki:

```
'transport' => 'postMessage',    
'partial_refresh' => array(
            'about_us_video_setting' => array(
                'selector' => '#youtube-video',
                'render_callback' => '__return_false'
            )
        )
```

Standard:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'about_us_video_setting' )->transport   = 'postMessage';

$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'about_us_video_setting', array(
            'selector' => '#youtube-video',
            'render_callback' => '__return_false',
        ) );
```

Comment: yes that great.. buy as you already figured it out the issue of double refresh and the pig icon that appears during refresh... it really funny for a very simple thing i have to follow the Weston Ruters guideline which is quite a long task for me..

Comment: @Taj Khan you can get rid of the Kirki "pig" icon easily, which helps quite a bit with how the refresh looks.

```function kirki_demo_configuration_sample_styling( $config ) {
 return wp_parse_args( array(
  'description'  => esc_attr__( 'The theme description.', 'kirki' ),
  'disable_loader' => true,
 ), $config );
}
add_filter( 'kirki/config', 'kirki_demo_configuration_sample_styling' );```

[Old kirki site config info](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512181848/http://aristath.github.io:80/kirki/docs/advanced/styling-the-customizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you can to do is extend `wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.Partial` in JavaScript to create a custom Partial type that overrides the `refresh` behavior to apply a JS-based live preview instead of doing an Ajax call to do a partial refresh request.

You can refer to an example in the [Customize Widget Sidebar Meta](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-widget-sidebar-meta) plugin, specifically in the [`sidebar_meta_background_color`](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-widget-sidebar-meta/blob/master/customize-widget-sidebar-meta-background-color-partial.js) partial type.

So if you register partials with this `sidebar_meta_background_color` type then they'd use this JS subclass with the overridden `refresh` method.

Comment: As i am not using any sidebars here, the solutions is not working with me.. my theme consists of mostly thememods. Can you tell me is it a criteria to use selective refresh if i want to show the edit icon? or do you have anything related to Kirki..

Comment: The example is to show you how to put your own JS code in the `refresh` method (line 40). By extending the partial (line 6), you have to modify the code.